# Format for saving to disk a canvas containing shapes, images, and text

Tags: c#, wpf

This is a WPF newbie's request for suggestions ( so there is no code here )

In my application, I present to the user a canvas onto which he can drag drop shapes, textboxes and images. Kind of like Visio. Now the user wants to save what he created to a file. How do I go about doing that, which classes do I use? And what data format choices do I have? What if I want to save it in XML format?

Most grateful for advice and pointers

Comment: Do You also want to read it later or not ?

Comment: yes, it has to be read back later for edits and saved back ad infinitum

Comment: you need to create model classes that are serializable. Update them when the user moves the shapes.

Comment: Please have a look that project. It has a really good saving management.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, I have picked up many good ideas from your discussion and suggestions. I will start exploring on these lines and hopefully a good solution will emerge

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a bitmap and then save the bitmap to file. To read it again just use `bitmap BMP = bitmap.FromFile(file);`

Update..

If you want to save all the changes that have been made you then need to create a file format probably something like:

Circle 1, 15 ,25, 100,250,10
Where the format is: 
    Shape size, positionx, positiony, rgb value

Comment: I think OP wants the objects to be still movable after loading

Comment: @thumbmunkeys as far as I'm aware there isn't a way to save an object to disk like that you have to serialise it first which is a nightmare because basically all of the changes the user made would have to be written to disk and then redone upon loading

Comment: yes, but that is exactly what needs to be done to achieve what OP wants

Comment: a file format is a not so good idea, it is far easier to make classes that can be serialized

Comment: So say the user placed an image at coordinates (X1, Y1) top left corner, and a textbox at coordinates (X2, Y2) top left corner, then saved the canvas to a file, closed the application, re-started the application, re-loaded the file. He should see his two objects in the same place where they were originally. THen he adds a few more objects, and saves to disk again ,.... and so on.

Comment: This is one way you can do so that also makes it easy to debug since you aren't working with individual bytes.

Comment: That should be it although if working with images you will need to save the images and provide the file path in the text document

Comment: @Cjen1 what do you mean by bytes? You can serialize easily into human readable formats like JSON or XML

Comment: So basically you just need to parse the text file into a 'history' of all the actions that the user has done and that would probably be useful anyways since then you would end up with a way to undo actions

Comment: @Cjen1 undo actions are normally in memory and not stored on disk

Comment: But in maintaining a list in memory it can easily be saved to disk

Comment: @Cjen1 you are mixing 2 different things in that case, undo and saving of the model. Usually this will bite you later on.

Comment: Please have a look that project:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part, it can provide a good perfective for you. It has all saving management, drag and drop etc. You can also download the project and source codes.

Comment: Thanks, I'm mostly working from first principals on my projects.